# SFML 2D game – Smooth spaceship movement

Tags: c++, user-interface, sfml

I am trying to make a simple game in C++ by using xcode as compiler and SFML as library. So far I have created a GUI, a background and a sprite (for the spaceship). I have also added arrow keys detection in order to be able to move the object, but the problem is that when i move the object it doesn't move smoothly and you can see it is kind of "jumping".

## main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Spaceship.hpp"
#include <vector>

// Here is a small helper for you! Have a look.
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

int main(int, char const**)
{

    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SpaceShuttle");
    window.setFramerateLimit(30);
    // Call to non-static member function without an object argument
    // Set the Icon
    sf::Image icon;
    if (!icon.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "space-shuttle.png")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());

    // Load a sprite to display
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "bg.png")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

    // Create a graphical text to display
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sansation.ttf")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Text text("SpaceShuttle K1LLM33K", font, 50);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    text.setPosition(100.0, 130.0);


    // Load a music to play
   /* sf::Music music; if (!music.openFromFile(resourcePath() + "nice_music.ogg")) { return EXIT_FAILURE; } 
    // Play the music
    music.play();
    */

    Spaceship spaceship(window);
    sf::Clock sf_clock;


    // Start the game loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {

        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }

            // Escape pressed: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
            // Move Spaceship
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) { spaceship.moveship('l'); }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) { spaceship.moveship('r'); }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) { spaceship.moveship('u'); }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) { spaceship.moveship('d'); }

        }
        // Clear screen
        window.clear();

        // Draw the sprite(s)
        window.draw(sprite);
        spaceship.drawsprite(window);

        // Draw the string(s)
        window.draw(text);

        // Update the window
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## Spaceship.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"
#include "Spaceship.hpp"

Spaceship::Spaceship(sf::RenderWindow& game_window){
    auto surface = game_window.getSize();
    ss_x = surface.x/2;
    ss_y = surface.y/2;
    ss_speed = 5;
    ss_width = 128;
    ss_height = 128;
    ss_radius = ss_width/2;

}
void Spaceship::drawsprite(sf::RenderWindow& game_window){
    sf::Texture ship;
    if (!ship.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "space-shuttle-64.png")) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    sf::Sprite ss_sprite(ship);
    ss_sprite.setPosition(ss_x - ss_sprite.getGlobalBounds().width/2, ss_y - ss_sprite.getGlobalBounds().height/2);
    game_window.draw(ss_sprite);
}

void Spaceship::moveship(char move){
    if(move == 'l'){ ss_x -= ss_speed;  }
    else if(move == 'r'){ ss_x += ss_speed; }
    else if(move == 'u'){ ss_y -= ss_speed; }
    else if(move == 'd'){ ss_y += ss_speed; }
}

Spaceship::~Spaceship(){}
```

## Spaceship.hpp

```
#ifndef Spaceship_hpp
#define Spaceship_hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Spaceship {
public:
    Spaceship();
    Spaceship(sf::RenderWindow&);
    ~Spaceship();
    void moveship(char);
    void drawsprite(sf::RenderWindow&);
private:
    signed int ss_x, ss_y;
    unsigned int ss_speed;
    int ss_width, ss_height, ss_radius;

};

#endif /* Spaceship_hpp */
```

Comment: Try with VSync instead of 30 FPS.

Comment: I can recommend reading [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) - it's relevant to your problem and a good read. See also [Integration Basics](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/).

Comment: @LogicStuff VSync is for fixing texture tearing issues, not really for fixing frame rate or solving smooth-movement issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been suggested in the comments, the problem here is that you are not taking into account the elapsed time between two frames in your computations. Hence what happens is that you are adding a fixed amount of velocity at any frame, ignoring the fact that two consecutive frames can need a very different time to finish.

There is another problem (which appears to be the main source of your issues): you are checking if keys are pressed *inside* the event loop. This is not correct, this will be true only if your key is pressed AND there have been other events during the loop. You need to check this out at every frame.

Another way to tackle the last issue is to have boolean flags that you set to `true` / `false` when you detect a `press` / `release` for the keys you want to test. If you have a look at the `isKeyPressed` method, you will also find out that this second method is ways more efficient than the first one.

The simplest way to change your main loop to get the elapsed time at every frame, [according to the docs](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/system-time.php) is something like this:

```
sf::Clock sf_clock;

// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen()) {
    // Get time elapsed since last frame
    float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();

    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        // Close window: exit
    }

    // Move Spaceship, this must be done outside of the pollEvent loop !
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) spaceship.moveship(dt, 'l');
    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) spaceship.moveship(dt, 'r'); 
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) spaceship.moveship(dt, 'u');
    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) spaceship.moveship(dt, 'd');

    }
    // Draw, etc..
}
```

Then you have to take `dt` into account in `moveship` method (I changed your `if / else if` in `switch case`, which I find cleaner in this case and should be more efficient):

```
void Spaceship::moveship(float dt, char move) {
    switch (move) {
        case 'l': ss_x -= dt * ss_speed_x; break;
        case 'r': ss_x += dt * ss_speed_x; break;
        case 'u': ss_y -= dt * ss_speed_y; break;
        case 'd': ss_y += dt * ss_speed_y; break;
    }
}
```

As suggested by Jesper Juhl, I did some [integration](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/) here (and you should really have a look at [the article](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/)).

BTW, I would suggest some modifications in your code:

```
// First of all, you should use floating-point values that you convert 
// in screen space at render time for your coordinates
// You could also think about using vectors instead, I won't here
class Spaceship {
private:
    float ss_x, ss_y;
    float ss_speed_x, ss_speed_y;

    // You should also store your sprite instead of creating it over
    // and over again
    sf::Sprite ss_sprite;
};


Spaceship::Spaceship(sf::RenderWindow& game_window) {
    // You can then take those modifications into account
    // in your constructor:
    auto surface = game_window.getSize();
    ss_x = ss_y = 0.5f;
    ss_speed_x = 5.f / surface.x;
    ss_speed_y = 5.f / surface.y;
    ss_width = 128;
    ss_height = 128;
    ss_radius = ss_width/2;

    sf::Texture ship;
    if (!ship.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "space-shuttle-64.png")) {
        // This is really an awful way to handle an error, but I won't
        // go into details here. A better way would be to have an Init()
        // method that returns an error code on failure for example.
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ss_sprite = sf::Sprite(ship);
    // http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a56c67bd80aae8418d13fb96c034d25ec
    ss_sprite.setOrigin(ss_width / 2, ss_height / 2);
}

// Finally, you reflect those modifications in your draw code
void Spaceship::drawsprite(sf::RenderWindow& game_window){
    auto size = game_window.getSize();
    ss_sprite.setPosition(ss_x * size.x, ss_y * size.y);
    game_window.draw(ss_sprite);
}
```

Comment: So i have tried with the modifications that you have made, and the ship moves very very slowly, increasing the ss_speed_x and ss_speed_y didnt help.

Comment: also It doesn't want to move smoothly

Comment: I wrote all of these without any testing, I will have a look at this

Comment: Just looking again at your code, you have to move the `if (sf::Keyboard::IsKeyPressed()` stuff outside of your event `while` loop. This should fix both the smoothness and the very slow movements

Comment: I think this was indeed the problem, I tried this out and this works properly ! I updated the answer to take that into account. I also changed the speed value to 250 instead of 5 (which was indeed very slow). [Here is the code I used](https://gist.github.com/Zouch/ff8a227305e4a2f95c7cceba3de2eb56).

Comment: could you please check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824786/sfml-sprite-white-square